# Ubuntu 18.04 on x86 wants to load arm64 repositories

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates

As a developer I **might** have broken something as my 18.04 tries to load packages also(?) for arm64:

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                 
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]

...

Fetched 494 kB in 2s (249 kB/s)                 

Reading package lists... Done

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why is this happening? Where does it get that `binary-arm64`?

There are no *.list under my /etc/apt/ that would include anything related to arm.

Comment: That can only happen if you or something you installed added the architecture.

Comment: Right. Do you happen to know any `dpkg` magic to find that possible package?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64`, I think

Comment: Thanks! :) Maybe you could convert that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a foreign architecture - "arm64" - that was added at some point.

It can be removed by running

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```